# unable to establish stream, will possibly retry: unable to fetch authentication token

Tags: datadog

Is it possible to run the `trace-agent` alone?

I am building it from the source and running it in a shell script

```
export DD_API_KEY=secret

/opt/exodus/bin/trace-agent &
```

However I am getting this error

> unable to establish stream, will possibly retry: unable to fetch authentication token: unable to read authentication token file: open /opt/datadog-agent/etc/auth_token: no such file or directory